# If $C_\mu\in\mathcal{T}$ for any $\mu\in M$, then $\bigcup_{\mu\in M} C_\mu\in\mathcal{T}$. Is my proof ok?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $S$ be a set.
> Let $\mathcal{T}_0\subset 2^S$.
> Let $\mathcal{T}:=\{B\subset S\mid B=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} B_\lambda, B_\lambda\in\mathcal{T}_0\}$.
> If $C_\mu\in\mathcal{T}$ for any $\mu\in M$, then $\bigcup_{\mu\in M} C_\mu\in\mathcal{T}$.

My proof:

> For each $\lambda\in \Lambda$, we can write $C_\lambda=\bigcup_{\mu\in M_\lambda} B_{(\lambda,\mu)}$, where $B_{(\lambda,\mu)}\in\mathcal{T}_0$.
> $\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda} C_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda} \left(\bigcup_{\mu\in M_\lambda} B_{(\lambda,\mu)}\right)=\bigcup_{(\lambda,\mu)\in\bigcup_{\lambda^{'}\in\Lambda}\{\lambda^{'}\}\times M_{\lambda^{'}}} B_{(\lambda,\mu)}\in\mathcal{T}$.

Is my proof ok or not?

Comment: Very difficult to follow with those indexes. If $C_\mu \in \mathcal T$, then $C_\mu = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\mu} B_
{\lambda}$ where $B_{\lambda} \in \mathcal T_0$. Thus, if $\Lambda := \bigcup_{\mu \in M} \Lambda_\mu$, we have
$$
\bigcup_{\mu \in M} C_\mu = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} B_{\lambda} \in \mathcal T.
$$

Comment: @azif00 Thank you very much for your answer.